# PHP json encoded data from MySQLi to PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to convert a site from MySQLi to PDO.    On a page of graphs, I'm having an issue where the graphs aren't working after I change to PDO.  The json output is identical, except with the PDO, the json output is wrapped inside of non-escaped double quotes, and then all quotes in the data are escaped.   Would anyone know how to modify the PDO query to remove the enclosing quotes and possibly all the interior double quote backslash escapes from the json output?

```
//MySQLi -----------------------------------------------
$con = mysqli_connect($db_server_address, $db_user_name, $db_password, $db_name) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "ERROR: Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "<br/><br/>";
}   

$sql = "
  SELECT * FROM table
";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($data);


//PDO ------------------------------------------
$dsn = "mysql:host=$db_server_ip;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_user_name, $db_password, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}    
$stmt = $pdo->query("
    SELECT * FROM table
");

$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Data Output:

```
//MySQLi Output-----------------------------------------------
[{"week_of":"2018-01-06","weekn":"1","Weekly_Ticket_Count":"8"},{"week_of":"2019-01-05","weekn":"1","Weekly_Ticket_Count":"12"}]

//PDO ------------------------------------------
"[{\"week_of\":\"2018-01-06\",\"weekn\":1,\"Weekly_Ticket_Count\":8},{\"week_of\":\"2019-01-05\",\"weekn\":1,\"Weekly_Ticket_Count\":12}]"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a result of PDO being used, but a result of double encoding it with json encode (right here)

```
$json = json_encode($results);
echo json_encode($json);
```

You encode it once when setting `$json` then you encode it again when echoing out said JSON. Which causes it to be double encoded (escaped `"` etc..)

All you need to do to fix it is remove one of them (or combine them)

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

OR

```
$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Vote to close: typo